# Android local broadcast doesn't receive

Tags: android, localbroadcastmanager

I want to send simple sata from an activity to another. Both are active at the time and I have registered LocalBroadcastManager. the sending part work but the receiving activity doesn't get anything.
BroadcastManager sending data part of the code :

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(SendingDataPageActivity.this);
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_INTENT);
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("test, "test");
            broadcastIntent.setAction("test, "test");
            broadcaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
            Log.d(TAG, "Broadcast sent..."); });
```

And For receiver:

```
public class RecievingDataPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "local broadcaster received...");}};
```

I have registered it in OnCreate:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver((receiver),
            new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_INTENT));
```

But still doesn't receive anything. Any help?

Comment: Ok I finally found the problem: I had unregistered the BroadcastReceiver in onStop() which caused ReceicerActivity to stop receiving it after going to a second activity especially the sender. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your action in the Intent constructor:

```
 Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_INTENT);
```

But 2 lines after, you are overriding it:

```
  broadcastIntent.setAction("test", "test");
```

You can only have one action so Intent gets lost.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line and try again.

broadcastIntent.setAction("test, "test");